# THREE.js + Mesh Modifiers

Tags: three.js, webgl, copperlicht, pre-3d

Coming from ActionScript + Papervision I am familiar with "AS3DMod" a library that modifies 3D meshes to bend, twist,etc. Now I am working with THREE.js and found this:"#MOD3 As3dMod 3D Modifier Library port for Javascript and Three.js, Pre3d and J3D and Copperlicht" but the code is outmoded for any remotely current versions of THREE.js (and also is written for canvas rendering, NOT webGL). The creator has not been able to update. Does anyone know of any similar 3D libs that can "bend ,twist, bloat" 3D meshes in webGL? I am not sufficiently skilled to update this myself.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of, but depending on what modifiers you are utilize, it may not be too difficult to write a modifier yourself. Typically you can reuse the logic in js for Canvas renderer, and as for WebGLRenderer, you can implement it in the Vertex shaders.